# App Organization for iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I have experience in C and C++, but near zero experience in Objective C, or Xcode4.

Im looking to create an app with a Tab bar, Navigation Bar, and Table Views. Based on the knowledge i have i assume i start from the top and drill down to the root?

First
Create myTableViewController class that will dynamically create tableview content and push its created view onto the navigation controller.
Then...
Create myNavController class that holds myTableViewController. with a method that creates a new item for myTableViewController.
Then...
Create the Tab Bar Controller that has the above as one of its tabs in an array along with some other tabs, set the tab bar controller as the root controller and display it to the window.

Is this the right direction to be thinking? Or am i horribly off course?

Comment: The "right direction to be thinking" is Interface Builder :)

Comment: EricS, start with the following sample: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 0):

I have an app with these same requirements. It's got a UITabBar, and in the different tabs each UITableViewController has a UINavigationController navigation bar at the top.

Here's how my App Delegate handles this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Create the UITabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    //Create the view controllers for our tabs
    UITableViewController *vc1 =     [[UITableViewController  alloc] init];
    UITableViewController *vc2 =     [[UITableViewController  alloc] init];
    UITableViewController *vc3 =     [[UITableViewController  alloc] init];
    UITableViewController *vc4 =     [[UITableViewController  alloc] init];
    UITableViewController *vc5 =     [[UITableViewController  alloc] init];

    //Create the Navigation Controllers for these views
    UINavigationController *nc1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                    initWithRootViewController:vc1] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nc2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                    initWithRootViewController:vc2] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nc3 = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                    initWithRootViewController:vc3] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nc4 = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                    initWithRootViewController:vc4] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nc5 = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                    initWithRootViewController:vc5] autorelease];


    //Make an array containing the view controllers
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc1, nc2, nc3, nc4, nc5, nil];

    //The NSArray has retained these controllers, we can now release them.
    [vc1    release];
    [vc2    release];
    [vc3    release];
    [vc4    release];
    [vc5    release];

    [nc1    release];
    [nc2    release];
    [nc3    release];
    [nc4    release];
    [nc5    release];

    //Assign the view controllers to the tab bar.
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    //Set tabBarController as rootViewController of window
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    //The window retains tabBarController, we can release our reference
    [tabBarController release];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Enjoy!